# Rails 5 asset precompiling fails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 5.2 (5.2.4.4) app deployed on Heroku, which I have successfully deployed in the past, but now fails to precompile assets when deploying. The error I get on `git push heroku master` is as follows:

```
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.4/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:23:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_9cb506be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
```

I have tried to precompile assets from the console with `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` and get the same error (abbreviated as it's the same trace as when deploying to Heroku):

```
jacquess-mbp-2:nepssa jacques$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/jacques/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@rails5.2.3/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.4/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:23:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
```

I looked in the `actionmailer/railtie.rb` file where the error occurs to get a sense of what was going on. The error appears to come from setting `default_url_options[:protocol]` when `force_ssl` is true.

```
      if app.config.force_ssl
        options.default_url_options ||= {}
        options.default_url_options[:protocol] ||= "https"
      end
```

Looking in `production.rb`, I do have `force_ssl` set to `true` and provide `default_url_options` (this code has worked correctly for many previous releases).

```
  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "www.nepssa.org", protocol: "https" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: '587',
    domain: 'heroku.com',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: 'apikey',
    password: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']
  }
```

Just for kicks, I turned off the `force_ssl` flag in `production.rb`, and found that I can precompile assets from the console (listing omitted, but all assets compile into `public/assets`). I guess I could deploy with precompiled assets, but it makes me uncomfortable to turn off the `force_ssl` to make this happen. Does not seem right.

At this point, I am not really sure what to look for. I don't know whether the `force_ssl` flag is a red herring, or a hint as to what I may be doing wrong. I am happy to share the content of additional files others may find pertinent.

Thank you in advance for any advice or help you can provide.